# How to perform keystroke inside powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, vmware, powershell-1.0, vmware-server

I have ps1 script to grab some information from the vmware cluster environment.

In some place of ps1 script requires the **ENTER** button keystroke.

So, How to do that ?

-Thanks

Comment: Which is the script i wrote, requires the **ENTER** keystroke.
instead of hitting **enter** button all the time, simply i want to automate.

Comment: Why does it require pressing enter? Are you executing read-host?

Comment: Myscript continuosly login/logout from several machine.
By the time of logout it requires confirmation, so i have to hit **enter** button.
This is the reason i want automate.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want PowerShell to send the **ENTER** keystroke to some interactive application?

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

If that interactive application is a PowerShell script, just use whatever is in the title bar of the PowerShell window as the argument to **AppActivate** (by default, the path to powershell.exe). To avoid ambiguity, you can have your script retitle its own window by using the `title 'new window title'` command.

A few notes:

- The tilde (~) represents the **ENTER** keystroke. You can also use `{ENTER}`, though they're not identical - that's the keypad's **ENTER** key. A complete list is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943%28v=office.10%29.aspx.
- The reason for the `Sleep 1` statement is to wait 1 second because it takes a moment for the window to activate, and if you invoke **SendKeys** immediately, it'll send the keys to the PowerShell window, or to nowhere.
- Be aware that this can be tripped up, if you type anything or click the mouse during the second that it's waiting, preventing to window you activate with **AppActivate** from being active. You can experiment with reducing the amount of time to find the minimum that's reliably sufficient on your system (**Sleep** accepts decimals, so you could try .5 for half a second). I find that on my 2.6 GHz Core i7 Win7 laptop, anything less than .8 seconds has a significant failure rate. I use 1 second to be safe.
- ***IMPORTANT WARNING:*** *Be extra careful if you're using this method to send a password, because activating a different window between invoking **AppActivate** and invoking **SendKeys** will cause the password to be sent to that different window in plain text!*

Sometimes **wscript.shell**'s **SendKeys** method can be a little quirky, so if you run into problems, replace the fourth line above with this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('~');
```

Comment: Thanks for that Add-Type addition to the end there. Was banging my head against the wall for an hour trying to get my script working.

Comment: What are the differences between using `Wscript.Shell` and using `SendKeys.SendWait`? Is one better that the other?

Answer (score 3):

```
function Do-SendKeys {
    param (
        $SENDKEYS,
        $WINDOWTITLE
    )
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    IF ($WINDOWTITLE) {$wshell.AppActivate($WINDOWTITLE)}
    Sleep 1
    IF ($SENDKEYS) {$wshell.SendKeys($SENDKEYS)}
}
Do-SendKeys -WINDOWTITLE Print -SENDKEYS '{TAB}{TAB}'
Do-SendKeys -WINDOWTITLE Print
Do-SendKeys -SENDKEYS '%{f4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Send "Enter" key to an App, for example for pressing "OK". Works great:**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

**# Get the desired process:**

```
$ProcessName = Get-Process -Name Calculator
```

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

**# If the process is actually running, bring it to front:**

```
If ($ProcessName)
{
   (New-Object -ComObject.Wscript.Shell).AppActivate((Get-Process $ProcessName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).MainWindowTitle)
}
```

**# Send "Enter" key to the app:**

```
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($ProcessName.ProcessName)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait({'~'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the `$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;` helped a script that was running in the background, it worked fine with just but adding `$wshell`. fixed it from running as background! `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("App Name")`