# How to send a keystroke to an application remotely with Powershell

Tags: powershell, remote-access, keystroke, wsh

I need to close an open application windows with a keystroke "q" via Powershell.

I found a solution here on stackoverflow ([How to perform keystroke inside powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849522/how-to-perform-keystroke-inside-powershell)) which works perfectly fine but only on a local machine:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('q')
```

Problem is, I need to close that windows on a remote machine. I tried it with a function:

```
$a = {
function Close_window {
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate(‘name of the window’)
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('q')
}
 Close_window($args)
}

$user = 'user'
$pw = 'password'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pw -asplaintext -force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $password

$servers = Get-content D:\test.txt
foreach ($server in $servers)
    {
        $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential

        invoke-command -session $session -ScriptBlock $a
        }
```

I also found this:

```
$scriptobjects = @()
$scriptobjects += {
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate(‘Untitled - Notepad’)
Sleep 2
$wshell.SendKeys('q')
}
$scriptobjects |foreach {& $_}
```

but I did not manage it to run on a remote machine, the result is always FALSE :-(

I would be happy if someone could help me with this!

Many thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: cant see a reason to use wscript when you have powershell. localy youd have smth like $p = Start-Process notepad -PassThru; $p.CloseMainWindow()

Comment: Is the session running as you user you are passing to the script?

Comment: Hi Jacqueline, Notepad is just an example. My main goal is to send the key 'q' to my application. The above example shows that it does work locally but I don't know how to run the following code block on a remote machine:                                                                                        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('q')

Answer (score 0):

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential

invoke-command -session $session -ScriptBlock {

    $p = Start-Process notepad -PassThru
    $p.CloseMainWindow()

}
```

Comment: I need to send the key 'q' to a running application/windows on a remote machine.