# How to ignore pause - press any key - in Powershell while executing file

Tags: .net, powershell

Using Powershell I am starting some executable using `invoke-expression` like:

```
Invoke-Expression "c:\exec.exe"
```

now my problem is this exec is showing something like "pause and press any key to continue".

I tried:

```
Function Run-Tool
{
    Invoke-Expression "c:\exec.exe"
    $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
```

But no luck.

My question is can I ignore that message some sort of suppression or is there a way to monitor output and simulate pressing any key?

Comment: Does the executable not have a `/quiet` switch?

Comment: May I ask what EXE that is? Is it a commonly available program maybe?

Comment: No it is an 3rd part app that I am trying to automatize.

Comment: Well, if it is a secret then I can only give the general advise to run that program with arguments like `/?` or `-?` or `-h` or `--help`, which are commonly used args for getting detailed help about possible command line arguments. With some luck you'll find the info you are looking for

Comment: ``"`n"|& C:\exec.exe`` might work

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Why not make it an answer? Or is that only a raw, untested guess?

Comment: @JensG It only works under certain circumstances (ie. not with `Console.ReadKey()`), OP doesn't provide enough detail to determine whether it would work in his case, but it's probably worth a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can redirect the enter key from powershell to the program by using processstartinfo and process :

```
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
$psi.FileName = "C:\yourexe.exe"; 
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false; 
$psi.RedirectStandardInput = $true;

$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);

Start-Sleep -s 2 # if your exe needs time to give output

$p.StandardInput.WriteLine("`n");
```

Answer (score 8):

If `exec.exe` is a regular console app expecting a newline a la:

```
Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Then you could just pipe a newline to it:

```
"`n" |& C:\exec.exe
```

Comment: Lovely solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey` will not do what you are after - the `ReadKey` function waits for input and returns info on the key that was pressed. So instead of sending input, it is waiting for input.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17851491/260393) is related to your situation - perhaps you can use the method suggested there.