# PowerShell send keys to uninstall prompt

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, sendkeys, silent

Can someone help me with a simple script that sends two keys (TAB and then Enter) to an uninstall prompt?
I am trying to silently uninstall IObit Uninstaller but the `/silent /supressmsgboxes` does not work.

This is what I have so far:

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\IObit\IObit Uninstaller\unins000.exe"

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

It doesn't return an error, but it doesn't work either.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Please show the code you have already tried and explain what _does not work_ means. Got error messages? Please add these to the question too.

Comment: From [here](https://gist.github.com/choco-bot/6d7bcc406412f0341e5ee19a199f8d86) (line 10), I think there is only one switch `/SILENT` needed: `& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IObit\IObit Uninstaller\unins000.exe' /SILENT`

Answer (score 0):

Goes without saying, but I would play with the uninstaller and make sure I've exhausted all the options before I play with any Send Keys paradigm.

I don't know exactly how you are running this. But, if you are going to send keys to the uninstall process there are a few things to look at.

First I think you have to add the assembly like:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

So I don't know why you didn't see errors, but if you were running a side script it may have exited.  Either way `Add-Type` won't hurt...

Second, I think you have to make sure the uninstaller is in focus.  There's an example of doing so using the WScript.Shell COM objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17851491/4749264)

In my rather lean experience with this it's a little harder to do Purely in PowerShell, but there's some work on PowerShell.org [here](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/sendkeys/). if you want to play with it.

Goggle has tons of similar things leveraging the Win32 API.

Comment: If this isn't helpful let me know, I'll delete the answer.