# Simulating an ESC button hit with powershell

Tags: powershell

I read that it was not there before,

but is there any solution to simulate an "ESC" key pressing from a powershell script?

Same as when a human would press the ESC key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these 2 resources:

[How to perform keystroke inside powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849522/how-to-perform-keystroke-inside-powershell)

https://www.jesusninoc.com/11/05/simulate-key-press-by-user-with-sendkeys-and-powershell/

But in a Nutshell:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('title of the application window')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys("{ESC}")
```